# Why do many languages use parentheses around `if` condition

Tags: language-design

Many programming languages require parentheses around the `if` condition.

For example:

```
if (x < 50)
{
}
```

Why can't it be written like this, without the parentheses:

```
if x < 50
{
}
```

Assuming that language designers are pragmatic people, why are the parentheses required?

Comment: _"why are the braces required?"_ What do you suggest be used instead to determine where the if-clause ends? Indentation? Some languages do this. `then`/`end if`? Some languages do that.

Comment: @Michael It took me a few minutes, but I realized that the question is asking about the *parentheses* around the *condition* `x < 50`, not the braces around the body. (I think there is a British/American disagreement over whether parentheses qualify as "braces" but I'm not entirely sure.) That said, I think this may still be opinion-based.

Comment: OP: to be totally clear, you are asking about why the syntax is `if (x<50) { }` instead of `if x < 50 { }`, correct? You should make this explicit in your question, because it's not obvious whether you're asking about the parentheses around the condition or the curly braces around the body. If you are talking about the parentheses: you still need something to separate `if` from the condition (so, either a space or an open parenthesis) and you need something to separate the condition from a single-statement body without braces (e.g., a colon, `:`), so it's the same number of chars either way.

Comment: @apsillers: Hmm, I think "brackets" could be used as synonym for parentheses. Braces are something else though, so if the OP really meant the parentheses around `x < 50` then he/she should edit the question to clarify that.

Comment: Yep, I meant parentheses. Edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: Rust doesn't use braces/brackets here. Also in the UK we never say 'braces' or 'parentheses' we say brackets for everything, brackets, square brackets, curly brackets etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, `if` takes actually a comma-operator, instead of just an expression. One can write:

```
int i = 0;
if (i = i + 1, i/2 > 0) {
}
```

So you need braces (parenthesis actually) here. The same is true for `while()` for example.

`return` operator in C however accepts just an expression, so it does not require parenthesis:

```
return i + 1;
```

though many programmers still write it like:

```
return (i + 1);
```

Comment: Cool, I did not know about the comma-operator. Why is this also needed in Java and C#?

Comment: @daramasala Well, because Java and C# syntax was historically derived from C/C++, so they kept the parenthesis but did not implement the comma operator. For instance Ada or Pascal have proper syntax (not derived from C) and do not require parenthesis in the if statement.

Comment: @Archie, your answer is not entirely correct. In C, C++, javascript and others C based languages, the operator `,` is just like any another operator that can be anywhere in code, so `return` can also have it.  The `,` returns the last expression in the list. Ex. In `int a = 5,6,7;` the value of `a` will be `7`. So `return "hello", 'a', 34, "world";` (without parenthesis) is also valid and will return the string `"world"`. Please see my answer to OP's question.

Comment: Er, this makes no sense, as WPomier says. The comma operator is like any other operator, plus you don’t have any ambiguity without parentheses even in your example with it.

Answer (score 1):

The real short answer is "Because their syntax/grammar language definition" and it's not anything related to parenthesis in expressions.

In the definition of languages the creator defines a set of rules that developers must follow.

In C, C++, Objective C, java, javascript and others C based languages, the parenthesis was used in their grammar to define how separate the conditional expression from the sentence to execute, but it was just for definition, because it was not required. Dennis Ritchie (C creator) could have used another way to separate conditional expression from true/false statement, but he chose parenthesis.

```
# Grammar of "if sentence" in C (in BNF)
<if-statement> ::= if ( <expression> ) <statement>
                 | if ( <expression> ) <statement> else <statement>
```

Languages like Modula2, Pascal, ADA, Delphi, Oracle PL/SQL and other Modula2 based languages don't define their grammar with parenthesis, but they use the keyword `then` to separate conditional expression from statement:

```
# Grammar of "if sentence" in Pascal (in BNF)
<if-statement> ::= if <expression> then <statement> 
                 | if <expression> then <statement> else <statement>
```

The same answer is valid for another sentences like `while` and `for`.

See complete C grammar [here](https://cs.wmich.edu/~gupta/teaching/cs4850/sumII06/The%20syntax%20of%20C%20in%20Backus-Naur%20form.htm), and Pascal grammar [here](http://condor.depaul.edu/ichu/csc447/notes/wk2/pascal.html) for reference.

Comment: It's like answering "why do we need to breath?" with "because we need to". In most languages, there is no reason for the parenthesis. So same as Python don't require them, other languages also could remove them

Comment: @daramasala, my short answer was more like a "by design", but also I did explain it: In every language, it's necessary a way to separate `conditional expression` from `sentence to execute`: In python the separator is `:` followed by new line, in pascal is the keyword `then`, in C are parenthesis. That's the reason. Now new languages can use the separator that they want in their initial design, but long term stablished languages cannot and shouldn't modify their design.

Comment: You got it wrong. I was asking why the `()` around the conditional are necessary

Comment: @daramasala: One reason is that in C, the braces can be omitted as in `if (cond) statement;`. If you omitted both – `if cond statement` – it’d be hard to parse. Other languages avoid this ambiguity by requiring braces, some other punctuator, or a keyword (like Rust, Python’s `:`, and several languages’ `then`, respectively).

Answer (score -4):

Simple answer: operator precedence. Remember basic highschool/elementary math: What's the answer for `7 * 4 + 3`? 31? or 49?

Braces allow you to impose your OWN precedence, to override what the language's natural precedence would be:

```
(7 * 4) + 3 -> 31 (the natural answer by BEDMAS rules)
7 * (4 + 3) -> 49
```

If you're talking about the `{}`, then that's to allow a multi-line block for the expression.

No braces:

```
if (...)
   a = 1;  // only this line is part of the "if"
   b = 1;  // ignore the indentation - this is always executed
```

v.s.

```
if (...) {
   a = 1;  // part of the "if"
   b = 1;  // also part of the "if"
}
```

Comment: Hhmm .. that doesn't explain the need for the outermost braces the OP is interested in.

Comment: _"Braces allow you to impose your OWN precedence ... `(7 * 4) + 3 -> 31`"_. Those are parentheses, not braces.

Comment: The question also uses the term incorrectly, to be fair ("braces around the if condition") -- I'm honestly not sure whether they really mean the parens around the condition or the braces around the consequent